# Qt/C++ QPainter::pen: Painter not active (QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1)

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

This is my code :

```
    QPaintDevice *paintDevice = this;
    QImage image;
    if (!isEnabled())
    {
        // If the globe covers fully the screen then we can use the faster
        // RGB32 as there are no translucent areas involved.
        QImage::Format imageFormat = ( ui->MarbleWidget_plan->viewport()->mapCoversViewport() )
                                     ? QImage::Format_RGB32
                                     : QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied;
        // Paint to an intermediate image
        image = QImage( rect().size(), imageFormat );
        image.fill( Qt::transparent );
        paintDevice = &image;
    }

gp = new GeoPainter ( paintDevice, ui->MarbleWidget_plan->viewport(), ui->MarbleWidget_plan->mapQuality() );
    drawMission();
```

I'm using Marble Widget :

http://edu.kde.org/marble/

and i'm trying to paint into this map  !!

And this is my drawMission():

```
void video::drawMission(){

    GeoDataCoordinates France( 2.2, 48.52, 0.0, GeoDataCoordinates::Degree );
    gp->setPen( QColor( 0, 0, 0 ) );
    gp->drawText( France, "France" );

    GeoDataCoordinates Canada( -77.02, 48.52, 0.0, GeoDataCoordinates::Degree );
    gp->setPen( QColor( 0, 0, 0 ) );
    gp->drawText( Canada, "Canada" );

    //A line from France to Canada without tessellation

    GeoDataLineString shapeNoTessellation( NoTessellation );
    shapeNoTessellation << France << Canada;

    gp->setPen( oxygenSkyBlue4 );
    gp->drawPolyline( shapeNoTessellation );

    //The same line, but with tessellation

    GeoDataLineString shapeTessellate( Tessellate );
    shapeTessellate << France << Canada;

    gp->setPen( oxygenBrickRed4 );
    gp->drawPolyline( shapeTessellate );

    //Now following the latitude circles

    GeoDataLineString shapeLatitudeCircle( RespectLatitudeCircle | Tessellate );
    shapeLatitudeCircle << France << Canada;

    gp->setPen( oxygenForestGreen4 );
    gp->drawPolyline( shapeLatitudeCircle );
}
```

And this is what i m getting

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::pen: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::fontMetrics: Painter not active
QPainter::fontMetrics: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::fontMetrics: Painter not active
QPainter::fontMetrics: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
```

Thank you for help ! and for your time

Comment: 1. you are doing strange things. Why you need paintDevice pointer?
2. you didn't show code which paints and where you are creating QPainter! Why didn't do it if you have this kind of problem!

Comment: i just modify my uestion to be more clear 

Thank you :)

Comment: And where is `QPainter::begin` or it's constructor called?

Comment: The QPainter::Begin is called indirectly by creating one with the QImage as the paint device

Comment: @user2216648 Show me the code.

Comment: what u need more ?? i think that i have put all the code that use the QPainter

Comment: Then post the `GeoPainter` constructor.  The code that triggers the error has not been given yet.

Comment: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3515 

Check the GeoPainter here

Comment: We need to know if the `MarbleWidget` or the `QImage` is being used as the paint device, and what it's state is when the `QPainter` is constructed.  If it's the widget being painted on, you should not be attempting to paint on it outside of a paint event.

Comment: In the line `paintDevice = &image;` you are taking address of object that will no longer exist at the moment `drawMission` is executed. You can't paint on a destroyed object!